# Disqus comments displays "Browser not supported" upon navigating with Turbolinks 5

Tags: javascript, disqus, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

When using Turbolinks 5 and the default Disqus comments embed code, you'll get a "Browser not supported" error and a warning in the console: "Use DISQUS.reset instead of reloading embed.js please."

When using the AJAX example in the Disqus docs, the embed.js warning goes away but not the "Browser not supported" warning.

How can I fix this without disabling Turbolinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, please take the default Disqus embed code:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

And add this:

```
s.setAttribute('data-turbolinks-track', 'reload');
```

So the code becomes:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
s.setAttribute('data-turbolinks-track', 'reload');
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

[Here is the Turbolinks documentation about data-turbolinks-track="reload"](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#reloading-when-assets-change)